# Derivation in a Landau-Lifshitz ferromagnetism paper

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, dispersion, ferromagnetism, domain-walls

I was reading the following paper by Landau and Lifshitz on ferromagnetism:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/B9780080363646500089

In the paper, the following expression is used for the density of the energy of the system (inhomogeneity+anisotropy):
$$ 1/2 \alpha s'^2+1/2 \beta (s_x^2+s_y^2) $$
Where $s$ is of course the magnetic moment field, $s'$ is its derivative with respect to $x$, and part of the problem is determining $\alpha/\beta$ (since it gives the square of the width of the intermediate region between magnetic domains). I've used here the slightly confusing notation of the paper, where I believe $1/2a$ means $(1/2)a$, on purpose because I don't know if I'm reading something wrong.

Near the end of page 15 (second page of the PDF) there is a derivation I don't understand. It says:

> Blockquote
> The numerical value of the constant α can be
> obtained approximately in the following way. The
> energy $1/2\alpha s'^2$ has its maximal possible value, when $s$
> changes its direction after every distance equal to the
> lattice constant $a$ of the crystal, i.e. when $\boldsymbol{s}'^2 \cong s^2/a^2$
> This maximum must be of the order $kT_c$ if $T_c$ is the Curie
> temperature (k is Boltzmann’s constant). Thus, we find
> approximately
> $$ \alpha = kT_c/as^2 $$

There's a few things I don't understand. First of all, it seems to me that the maximum of $s'^2$ should be $(2s)^2/a^2$, since it changes direction completely (therefore the total change is twice its magnitude). But I understand it if it's just an order of magnitude calculation. However, I am then unsure exactly where the Curie temperature comes from, and what's more, the final formula does not seem right to me. My calculation would be:
$$ \frac{\alpha s^2}{2 a^2}  = kT_c$$
therefore:
$$ \alpha = \frac{2 a^2 kT_c}{s^2}$$
But this is not at all the formula they find, unless, I've horribly misread something. In fact their formula doesn't even seem dimensionally correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, the expression is for the energy *density*, so its dimensions are [Energy / volume]. Meaning that $\alpha$ has dimensions of $[E a^2 s^{-2} a^{-3}] = [E s^{-2} a^{-1}]$ as they have in their formula

Comment: Hmmm I think I see now... Are the rest of the questions just due to taking order of magnitude approximations?

Comment: yes as far as I can see. they are interested in how things scale with the different parameters, so its order of magnitude approximation